# Autopopulate zipcode when contact name is selected through lookup

Tags: workflow

I have   customobject   where  i  try to select contactname through lookup  relationship .By selecting contactname      zipcode field from contact   should be populated before saving

Comment: And have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried cross object formula field

Comment: Please update your post with more details such as where the zipcodes are stored and examples of what you have tried.  Also, standard page or VF page?

Comment: zipcode are stored in contacts and i used standard page

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a formula field it will update after the record has been saved. 
If your requirement is to populate zipcode before saving, then use a custom vf page and use action support on contact lookup field with event on change.

Update : use this for reference [Populate address field upon Contact lookup selection](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14381/populate-address-field-upon-contact-lookup-selection?rq=1)